# 'QtSerialPort' file not found on Qt 5.12.0 on macOS 10.13.6 clang 7.0

Tags: c++, qt, qtserialport

I'm trying to add the QtSerialPort module, and the QSerialPort file isn't found.

I followed the command line steps on https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Serial_Port but it still says that the QtSerialPort file is not found. I have both directories qtserialport and qtserialport-build. I couldn't find the branch for git checkout qt5.x.y so I did git checkout v5.12.0.

When I go to /Users/rmec/Qt/5.10.0/ios/include I don't see QSerialPort or QtSerialPort

When I hover over #include it says "QSerialPort: No such file or directory

Comment: Did you use `QT += serialport` like the instructions say? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-index.html

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, and when I use QT += serialport I get unknown module(s) in QT: serialport

Comment: Did you do the `make install` step from the shell? Was it successful? It seems like it did not install.

Comment: Last time I tried Qt 5.12 on macOS 10.13, my whole project got buried under a blizzard of errors. I had to opt for Qt 5.11, which seemed to work fine. I _think_ Qt 5.12 is more targetted for macOS 10.14 ([Qt blog](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2018/11/08/qt-macos-10-14-mojave/)), so _perhaps_ consider either downgrading your Qt or upgrading your mac.

Answer (score 1):

> /Users/rmec/Qt/5.10.0/ios/include

QSP does not supported for iOS!

BTW: I don't understand why you need to build the QSP from sources, because it already is shipped with the Qt installer (for Mac OSX only, not for iOS).